# How to filter cell arrays in Matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell

I want to filter the following cell array in Matlab:

A =

```
[1x3 double]    [3]    [5]    [6]
[1x3 double]    [3]    [4]    [5]
[1x3 double]    [6]    [7]    [8]
```

How can filter out only the rows where the value in column 3 is larger than 4? As a result it should then give me rows 1 and 3.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do the comparison and then select the returned rows out of `A`:

```
A([A{:,3}]>4, :);
```

In the above,

```
[A{:,3}]>4
```

yields

```
 1 0 1
```

showing which rows have a third column greater than `4`. Choosing these rows out of `A` gives you the answer you want. (Updated after @LuisMendo's comment)

Comment: You can skip `'`: `A(([A{:,3}]>4),:);` (and anyway it would be safer to use `.'`,  because `'` does a conjugate transpose)